# Create a column in MySQL that automatically fills 0 or 1 based on presence of substring on previous column

Tags: mysql, if-statement, auto-generate

I have this database at MySQL that has, among others, the following columns: Country, Level and Branch.
I would like three new columns to this database indicating wether there's a comma (1) or not (0) on each of this three columns. Like this:
[image: example]

I want these columns to be automatic, so new observations can be added to the table without the need of running the same script again and again to update the values shown there. I know how to do this in excel with IF functions, but I got stuck on MySQL. I have tried this:

```
alter table countries
add bol_coutnry int GENERATED ALWAYS AS (if(`COUNTRY` LIKE '%{$,}%',1));
```

among other variations of the same code but didn't even run. Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: ```ADD bol_country INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS (LOCATE(',', `country`) > 0);```. PS. Storing multi-valued CSV is not good idea, this makes problematic the effective data processing.

Comment: Perhaps see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad

Comment: Yes I'm aware of how badly designed this is. I have very little autonomy on the changes I can make to this database due to compatibility with previous (similarly badly designed) systems that use it. My hope is to properly fix this and other issues in the future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply write a trigger to do the job.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `countries_before_insert` BEFORE INSERT ON `countries` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    SET NEW.bot_country = IF(POSITION(',' IN NEW.Country) = 0, 0, 1);
    SET NEW.bot_level = IF(POSITION(',' IN NEW.Level) = 0, 0, 1);
    SET NEW.bot_branch = IF(POSITION(',' IN NEW.Branch) = 0, 0, 1);
END
```

It will auto populate these columns in your table. Make sure you do also write `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger too, so when changing a value should also update these 3 columns.

You can also use [`INSTR`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_instr) at place of [`POSITION`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_position)

Comment: @jncoe note that sometimes the cure is worse than the disease